# MongoDB: Validating documents that already exist in a collection

Tags: mongodb, validation

Recently I've done some reading and experimenting with the MongoDB `db.collection("name").validate()` operation (see [here](https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/document-validation-part-1-adding-just-the-right-amount-of-control-over-your-documents)). This is fine and dandy to use when you are setting your database up, but when there are documents already in the collection before the validation is added, none of those documents are checked for validation. How does one validate the documents that already exist in the mongoDB?

Comment: What MongoDB version are you running?

Comment: I'm running version 3.4

Comment: Have a read of this: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/document-validation/#existing-documents

Answer (score -1):

if you have inserted the documents in the collection and now you want to validate the collection.

For this, you have to use runCommand. In runCommand, you have to specify the collection name for which you want to validate, and provide data fields for which you are going to apply validation-

EX-

```
db.runCommand( {
   collMod: "collectionName",
   validator: { $jsonSchema: {
      bsonType: "object",
      required: [ "variable1", "variable2" ],
      properties: {
         variable1: {
            bsonType: "string",
            description: "must be a string and is required"
         },
         variable2: {
            bsonType: "string",
            description: "must be a string and is required"
         }
      }
   } },
   validationLevel: "moderate"
} )
```

For more detail you can visit-
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/schema-validation/#existing-documents

Comment: but how does this check the existing entries? Your solution still only checks new insertions.

Comment: There is a explicit statement in your own link, why this is not a solution to the posted question: `Validation occurs during updates and inserts. When you add validation to a collection, existing documents do not undergo validation checks until modification.`